# Is it possible to use Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls in C++/CX UWP project?

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

Is it possible to use Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls in C++/CX project?

If yes, what is needed to do it?

Best regards,
Michał

Comment: As @IInspectable said, the Windows Community Toolkit is available as a Visual Studio NuGet package for new or existing C# and VB.NET projects(e.g. create a c# uwp app). In c++/cx, you can't use Windows Community Toolkit, if you want to achieve the similar effect, maybe you could try to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/) is exclusive to C# and VB.NET. You cannot directly consume it from a native application written in C++/CX or C++/WinRT.

Comment: Is it any workaround available which allows to use it in project?